# Clonar nodos y cambiar valores en javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

¿Cómo puedo clonar un nodo y cambiarle los valores a los hijos hagan de cuenta un texto que este cambiando por cada condición que se le ponga?

Utilicé un setInterval para que la función se este llamando a cada rato y así las condiciones siempre se ejecuten pero no me cambia el texto a la hora de clonarlo, simplemente me clona el valor del texto original al plasmarlo en el document con appendChild o append.

Es para una alarma y ando tratando de mostrar tal texto para la alarma, o sea, si se ejecuta mañana pues que me muestre ese texto o para cuando se ejecuta más tarde o cuando tenga que sonar la alarma.

O sea, funciona pero con la primera alarma ya cuando agrego unas más, el texto ya no cambia por defecto solo dice "Programando alarma".

Comment: Si pones el código con lo que has intentado será mucho más facil conseguir buenas respuestas

Comment: ya lo resolviste? tengo un problema similar, quiero clonar varios Nodos, pero que cada uno tenga datos diferentes que resivira a través de un formulario.